# Create a link in /usr/bin for python?

Tags: python, local

We have a large number of scripts on an old CentOS system that begin with **#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7**. We are setting up a new host with RH EL7 and noticed that Python 2.7.5 is installed at /usr/bin/python2.7 instead of /user/local/bin/python2.7. This means that the old scripts won't be able to find python on the new RH system.

To avoid editing all the scripts, would simply adding at link at **/usr/local/bin/python2.7** pointing to **/usr/bin/python2.7** work? Is there a downfall to this approach?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On almost any modern distro, `python` points to `python3` which in turn points to `python3.7`. So no, there's no down side to symlinking like this.

Just know what you're doing and why you're doing it.

[image]

Removed my comment and added it as an answer, since the question doesn't appear to be closing and others were posting information on the topic as answers.

Answer (score 1):

### Do it

*"adding at link at /usr/local/bin/python2.7 pointing to /usr/bin/python2.7"* is OK.

What is not ok is the other way round.

You put what you want in `/usr/local/bin/`, but avoid messing with `/usr/bin/`, which contains important stuff (but you don't do it so that's ok, just make sure you know what you're doing).

Xcode doesn't like symlinks, other than that, to my knowledge, there is no down side.

If you're on Mac (and use Xcode), you may want to read [*"Xcode, for whatever reason, will not let you use the symbolic link at /usr/local/bin/python"*](https://ericasadun.com/2016/12/04/running-python-in-xcode-step-by-step/) to fix that issue.